# How to set color of gwt material elements different from theme color?

Tags: java, css, gwt, material-design

How can we set different color for different radio button or check box in gwt material design? By default the the color of these elements if of theme color.
But i want to set color for elements different from theme color

Answer (score 0):

I think that one solution consist to modify the GWT CSS file.

But, you can also use the link bellow. It's provide a manual for how to styling GWT components.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since GMD doesn't offer the setter for checkbox and radio button color, you will probably need to overwrite the style from the theme CSS file by adding the following css code into your own override.css. I picked red color in my example but you should overwrite it with your desired color. Hope it helps.

**Checkbox**

```
/*default type*/
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    border-right-color: red !important;
    border-bottom-color: red !important;
}
/*filled-in type*/
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + label:after {
    border-color: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

**Radio Button**

```
/*default type*/
[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    border-color: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}

/*with-gap type*/
[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + label:before {
    border-color: red !important;
}
[type="radio"].with-gap:checked + label:after {
    border-color: red !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
```